# How do you create loops based on db fields?

Tags: php, loops

```
echo '<div>';
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ 
    if ($row['Course']!=$old_id) 
    {
        $old_id=$row['Course'];
        echo '</div>
                  <div class="sectitle">'.$row['Course'].'</div>
                  <div style="width:100%;float:left">';
    }
    if ($row['Approved']==1) 
    {
        $coursedate=date("M Y", strtotime($row['Submitted']));
        echo '<div class="nbutton">
            <ul>
                <li><strong><a target="_new" href="' . $row['AssignmentURL'] . '">' . $row['URL'] . '</a></strong></li>
                <li>Instructor: ' . $row['LastName'] . ', ' . $row['FirstName'] . '</li>
                <li>Book: '.$row['TextBook'].'</li>
                <li>Submitted: '.$coursedate.' </li>
            </ul>
        </div>';
    }
}
echo '</div>';
```

I'm learning PHP and wrote this in a hurry. Now that I'm understanding more about how loops work, I'm trying to come back to this and reformat it.

The $row contains a value for the Course which is something like ESL 1010 or ENGL 1010, and it's a standard value for each entry. How can I structure my looping so that it uses something that includes this method I am familiar with:

```
$courses=array_unique($row['Course'])
foreach ($courses as $course)
{... This is where I get lost.
```

Sorry if this is a really simple fix. I just can't seem to wrap my brain around it.

Comment: `$row['Course']` is an array??

Comment: no, that's what I'm saying is how can I get the same effect as $courses=array_unique($row['Course']) ... sorry, this was not clear.

Comment: It's still not clear what you want. `array_unique()` requires its parameter to be an array, and it removes duplicates from it. But `$row['Course']` is just a single string, so what does it mean to remove duplicates?

Comment: I need to know how to make an array of all the Courses. Like how do you run down the list of rows in mysql and make an array of each Course field?

Then array_unique($array_of_courses)

Then run a loop that will spit out the assignments listed under each course, then move on to the next course, and give those assignments, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$courses = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $courses[] = $row;
}
```

Now `$courses` is an array holding all the courses, you have extracted the data from the MySQL result set and stored it in an array. Do with it whatever you want now.

If possible you should avoid doing this however, as it takes longer and uses more memory than iterating through the result set a row at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If this does infact use more memory, I will just stick with the current way that I set $old_id. I was able to add another if-statement after the else which closes up the div and sets the $old_id at that point, instead of in the first if-statement. One of my goals was to get rid of the silly empty div at the very beginning.